# 'Given that' in a matrix

Tags: symbols, matrices

I am trying to create the following equation where I have n given that y where y must be split among two lines. This is the code I have so far (which will give me the big braces).

```
\left\{ 
  \begin{matrix}
  ...
  \end{matrix}
\right\}
```

Any idea how I can fill the matrix to obtain the following please? Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not sure what you have in mind for the dots.  Here, I show it with either a `matrix` or an `aligned` block.

Thanks to egreg for the `\middle` reminder.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \left\{ n\,\middle| \begin{matrix}2x & y\\3x & 2y\end{matrix}\right\}
\]
\[
  \left\{ n\,\middle| \begin{aligned} z &= 2x + y\\z &= 3x - 2y\end{aligned}\right\}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @egreg I sure did, though I can't say that I am enamored of the spacing.

Answer (score 9):

Use `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiterX{\Set}[1]{\lbrace}{\rbrace}{\activatebar #1}

\newcommand{\activatebar}{%
  \begingroup\lccode`~=`| \lowercase{\endgroup\let~}\activebar
  \mathcode`|="8000
}
\newcommand{\activebar}{\nonscript\;\delimsize\vert\nonscript\;\mathopen{}}

\begin{document}

\[
\Set{n|n>0}
\Set[\big]{n|n>0}
\Set*{n|\begin{matrix} n>0 \\ n<42 \end{matrix}}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Important note: don't use `|` for other purposes in the argument of `\Set`; it shouldn't be used anyway, preferring `\lvert` and `\rvert` for the absolute value. Or, of course, with macros based on `mathtools`, such as

```
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\abs}{\lvert}{\rvert}
```

Comment: Very nice indeed!